# Have done vs Did

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

I wonder which of these sentences sound more natural to the ears of native English speakers.

> I have done/finished/received my education from high school to college in the Netherlands.

or

> I did/finished/received my education from high school to college in the Netherlands.

Assuming I will further talk about my edcuation after, which of the sentence will be a better choice for me to use?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the above.  Instead we *attend* or *go to* school in some location:

> I **attended** high school and college in the Netherlands.

The simple past is normally correct, unless you plan to relate your education to some later event.

> I **had attended** high school and college in the Netherlands, before I moved to Canada to complete my graduate degree.

On completing high school/college/university, you do *receive* a degree of some kind, and it's this *completion* which most people talk about in their educational history.

(Edit) Also, as Jason Bassford suggests,

> I **was educated** at ...

is correct, but more formal.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I think I heard people saying "I did/have done my education...". Is it considered ungrammatical or usage of another region?

Comment: @MAT I would say *I was* ***educated at*** or *I received my* ***education from***. (Or simply, *I* ***went to school at***.)  I would not say *I* ***did my education at***. I can't recall that turn of phrase being used by anybody I've listened to either.

Comment: @MAT  "I **did my education**" sounds like a non-native speaker.  But I do like Jason Bassford's comment, and will include that in my answer.